# How do I delete properly node_modules from Mac?

Tags: macos, npm, node-modules

My Mac is running low on space. The first place I always look is the `node_modules` directory as I run many projects at a time - as I'm sure we all do!

I am not sure whether I should just clean all or leave globally installed. Go to the directories where you have `node_modules` installed and print them/this what I did:

```
$ find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune -print | xargs du -chs
```

Result:

```
5.4M    ./.npm-packages/lib/node_modules
 19M    ./.nvm/versions/node/v15.3.0/lib/node_modules
2.4M    ./Desktop/note/server/node_modules
 59M    ./Desktop/jsamazona/frontend/node_modules
6.3M    ./Desktop/jsamazona/node_modules
228M    ./Desktop/react-with-leaflet-master/node_modules
254M    ./Desktop/npmapp/npmapp/node_modules
311M    ./Desktop/npmapp/node_modules
387M    ./Desktop/speechly_expense_tracker_project-main/node_modules
347M    ./Desktop/my-gatsby-project/node_modules
du: ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/bootstrap: No such file or directory
du: portfolio/node_modules: No such file or directory
 98M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/simplefolio/node_modules
305M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/myportfoliosite/node_modules
 81M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/portfolio20/node_modules
421M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/vania-portfolio/node_modules
706M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/portfolio/node_modules
 81M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/myportfolio/node_modules
302M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/portfoliob/studio/node_modules
344M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/portfoliob/node_modules
595M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/vdfolio/node_modules
584M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/vdfolio/vdfolio-api/node_modules
584M    ./Desktop/PORTFOLIOS/vdfolio/vdfolio/node_modules
261M    ./Desktop/recipeui/node_modules
291M    ./Desktop/recipeui/DEVTODO/quizapp/node_modules
716K    ./Desktop/recipeui/DEVTODO/LOco/node_modules
389M    ./Desktop/GATSBYS/gatsby-bloga/node_modules
467M    ./Desktop/GATSBYS/gatsby-bootcamp/node_modules
457M    ./Desktop/GATSBYS/my-gatsby-project/node_modules
510M    ./Desktop/GATSBYS/gatsby-simplefolio/node_modules
295M    ./Desktop/GATSBYS/gotsbystyle/node_modules
4.0K    ./Desktop/yarn/node_modules
100K    ./Desktop/project_chat_application/node_modules
368M    ./Desktop/react-three/node_modules
6.5M    ./Desktop/MAP/node_modules
260M    ./Desktop/MAP/map/node_modules
501M    ./Desktop/wwwg/node_modules
259M    ./Desktop/DEPLOYED/todo/node_modules
739M    ./Desktop/DEPLOYED/ecommerce2/node_modules
435M    ./Desktop/DEPLOYED/gatsby-simplefolio/node_modules
275M    ./Desktop/DEPLOYED/mern-tracker/node_modules
303M    ./Desktop/DEPLOYED/mern-tracker/mern-tracker/node_modules
 14M    ./Desktop/DEPLOYED/mern-tracker/mern-tracker/backend/node_modules
584M    ./Desktop/DEPLOYED/vdfolio/node_modules
311M    ./Desktop/covidtr/covidtr/node_modules
267M    ./Desktop/recepapp/node_modules
294M    ./Desktop/vdapp/node_modules
255M    ./Desktop/threeui/node_modules
584M    ./Desktop/my-project/node_modules
554M    ./Desktop/my-project/my-project/node_modules
du: ./Desktop/node-express: No such file or directory
du: /server/node_modules: No such file or directory
du: ./Desktop/node-express: No such file or directory
du: /server/memo-pad2/node_modules: No such file or directory
du: ./Desktop/node-express: No such file or directory
du: /client/node_modules: No such file or directory
 16M    ./Desktop/tinder/tinder-backend/node_modules
372M    ./Desktop/tinder/tinder/node_modules
249M    ./Desktop/house3D/house3d/node_modules
354M    ./Desktop/mernshop/frontend/node_modules
 59M    ./Desktop/mernshop/node_modules
 15M    ./Desktop/mernblog/server/node_modules
356M    ./Desktop/mernblog/client/node_modules
du: ./Library/Application: No such file or directory
du: Support/vscode-sqltools/node_modules: No such file or directory
106M    ./Library/Caches/typescript/4.1/node_modules
210M    ./Library/Caches/typescript/4.0/node_modules
```

The list is much longer, what should I do?

I am thinking of deleting all and reinstalling node again.

```
$ find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -print -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Advise by Thomas Large [how to delete all node_modules on Mac](https://medium.com/@tomlarge/how-to-delete-all-node-modules-folders-from-your-mac-60b5ce9949cf)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete **all node modules folders from your machine**, or from any directory and all its subdirectories the following commands work:

```sh
# MACOS
cd <directoryToDeleteFrom>
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -print -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

```
# WINDOWS
cd <directoryToDeleteFrom>
FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" rm -rf "%d"
```

```
# POWERSHELL
Get-ChildItem -Path "." -Include "node_modules" -Recurse -Directory | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Credit to [trillion.io](https://trilon.io/blog/how-to-delete-all-nodemodules-recursively).

The node modules can then be re-installed whenever you are using a particular project with `npm install` and the like, or to save space you can try  [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) (though I have had errors with it and specific projects such as react-native).

Answer (score 3):

If this is just within a local dev project and you installed them yourself, you can just run `rm -Rf node_modules` to delete them, then run `npm install` to reinstall when you are ready.

Comment: no, it's not, this is in my entire system, all the projects, I copy/paste just a bit another wise it will be a long story. I tried to publish my own package.json on npm.js and somehow messed up the hostname/IPrequest to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames. So, the idea is to reinstall node, hoping that will fix it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to clean some space on your drive, you can look for temp files and that kind of data to save some space too.

Comment: or use a cleanup app, which will do a better job, the question is about node_modules overloading my system, and can I just delete all of them and start on a clean slate.